# Installing SQL Server Express (Free Version) w/Company Client Version Being on Machine Already

Tags: sql-server

On my company computer, we have a license for the client version of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.  Would installing the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express component (a free component I would download just so I could create my own local database) cause compatibility issues?  This trial version would be removed after a specified about of time I assume.

Answer (score 1):

You can install multiple instances of SQL Server on a single machine. There shouldn't be any compatibility issues with any installations you have now, just be aware that there can only be one default instance on a machine (regardless of version or edition).

Comment: The 'client version' is SQL Server Management Studio.  It's a nearly 500+ MB install bundled with Visual Studio, native client, etc.  I'll confirm tomorrow on the exact version & name of the install.Background is mostly Oracle so I referred to this as the client version.  I wanted to use the Express component so I could use my computer as a local database server & create my own local databases but also connect to company servers to do work through the studio application.  One of the IT guys is worried about compatibility if I install the Express component but it does not appear to be an issue.

Comment: @whoknows you should be able to install an instance of Express with no problems.

Comment: Hi Aaron, to help placate that IT guy, which products of SQL Server would enable me to uuse my computer as a local database server & create my own local database instance: 2008R2 stand,enterprise and the developer edition.  I'm assuming the enterprise and developer editions are correct? thx

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can install any edition you want / need, provided that your operating system supports that edition and that you have a valid license (for non-free SKUs).

Comment: Well, I want to know which edition above enables me to use my local machine as a server for a local database (Link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx).  The edition that I have installed does not appear to have this ability.  I don't want to use company servers that I don't have admin rights on.  This database I would have admin rights on.  I hope this explanation makes more sense.  Thank you.